# How to apply filter based feature selection for logistic regression in R's caret package?

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I am trying to apply filter based feature selection in `caret` package for logistic regression. I was successful at using `sbf()` function for random forest and LDA models (using `rfSBF` and `ldaSBF` respectively).

The way I modified `lmSBF` is as follows:

```
# custom lmSBF
logisticRegressionWithPvalues <- lmSBF
logisticRegressionWithPvalues$score <- pScore
logisticRegressionWithPvalues$summary <- fiveStats
logisticRegressionWithPvalues$filter <- pCorrection
logisticRegressionWithPvalues$fit <- glmFit

# my training control parameters for sbf (selection by filter)
myTrainControlSBF = sbfControl(method = "cv", 
                               number = 10, 
                               saveDetails = TRUE, 
                               verbose = FALSE, 
                               functions = logisticRegressionWithPvalues)
# fit the logistic regression model
logisticRegressionModelWithSBF <- sbf(x = input_predictors, 
                                      y = input_labels, 
                                      sbfControl = myTrainControlSBF)
```

Here, `glmFit` function (mentioned above) is as follows:

```
# fit function for logistic regression
glmFit <- function(x, y, ...) {
    if (ncol(x) > 0) {
        tmp <- as.data.frame(x)
        tmp$y <- y
        glm(y ~ ., data = tmp, family = binomial)
    }
    else nullModel(y = y)
}
```

But while calling `logisticRegressionModelWithSBF` I am getting an error as:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "inputs must be factors"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just an hypothesis: maybe some of your data that should be factors are character strings? try to coerce the in you model calling with `as.factor(<variable>)`